# Sqllite sum () returns wrong value while join Second Table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to calculate sum of two columns from two table, Group by Date and Join that both table together

**Query 1**

```
select 
    Dates
    , ifnull( sum(Amount),0) As ETA 
from 
    Expence as t1 
where 
    t1.Dates IN (
        select distinct Dates As A from ( 
            select 
                Expence.Dates 
            from
                Expence 

            union all 

            select 
                Pass.Dates 
            from
                Pass 
                left join Expence 
                    on Pass.Dates=Expence.Dates
        )
    ) 
group by 
    dates
```

**Query 2**

```
select 
    Dates
    , ifnull( sum(Paid),0) As PTP
    , ifnull( sum(TotalAmount),0) As PTA 
from 
    pass As t2 
where 
    t2.Dates IN (
        select distinct 
            Dates As A 
        from ( 
            select 
                Expence.Dates 
            from 
                Expence 

            union all 

            select 
                Pass.Dates 
            from 
                Pass 
                left join Expence 
                    on Pass.Dates=Expence.Dates
        )
    ) 
group by 
    dates
```

Both queries work independently, but return an incorrect answer when joined together.

```
select distinct 
    t.Dates
    ,PTP
    ,PTA
    ,ETA 
from (
    select 
        Dates
        , ifnull( sum(Paid),0) As PTP
        , ifnull( sum(TotalAmount),0) As PTA 
    from 
        pass As t2 
    where 
        t2.Dates IN (
            select distinct 
                Dates As A 
            from( 
                select 
                    Expence.Dates 
                from 
                    Expence 

                    union all 

                select 
                    Pass.Dates 
                from 
                    Pass 
                    left join Expence 
                        on Pass.Dates=Expence.Dates
            )
        ) 
    group by dates
) AS t
, (
    select 
        Dates
        ,ifnull( sum(Amount),0) As ETA 
    from 
        Expence as t1 
    where 
        t1.Dates IN (
            select distinct 
                Dates As A from ( 
                    select 
                        Expence.Dates 
                    from Expence 

                    union all
                        select 
                            Pass.Dates 
                        from 
                            Pass 
                            left join Expence 
                                on Pass.Dates=Expence.Dates
                )
        ) 
    group by dates
) AS P
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select distinct tdate AS `DATE`,PTA AS `TOTAL AMOUNT` ,PTP AS `TOTAL PAID`,ETA AS `TOTAL EXPENCE`, PTA -PTP  AS `BALANCE` from((
select Dates As tdate,ifnull( sum(Paid),0) As PTP, ifnull( sum(TotalAmount),0) As PTA from pass As t2 where t2.Dates IN  (select distinct Dates As A from( select Expence.Dates from Expence union all select Pass.Dates from Pass left join Expence on Pass.Dates=Expence.Dates))
 group by dates)AS t left join
(

(select Dates as pdate,ifnull( sum(Amount),0) As ETA from Expence as t1 where t1.Dates IN  (select distinct Dates As A from( select Expence.Dates from Expence union all select Pass.Dates from Pass left join Expence on Pass.Dates=Expence.Dates))  group by dates 

)AS p)  ON   tdate=pdate) where tdate between '24-01-2019' AND '25-01-2019'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting incorrect results because the query as you've written it is nonsensical.

Your `from` clause is pulling from two [derived tables](https://www.apress.com/gp/blog/all-blog-posts/common-table-expressions-vs-derived-tables/12348908) that you've declared. Because you have not declared any join logic, sqlite is assuming a [natural join](https://www.guru99.com/sqlite-join.html#4). This means that for every column brought in (for both tables), it's checking for a match in every row.

Since these queries appear to have almost nothing to do with each other, you're not often going to get much in the way of matching records.

I don't know much about your data, so giving better advice beyond "run them separately" is going to be difficult. My assumption is that you're going to want to add `on t.Dates = P.Dates` to the end of your join statement.

Comment: @Donkkas: If that solved helped or solved your problem, please upvote/accept the answer as may be appropriate.